# ReflectionException Class App\Controller\MyController does not exist error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-artisan

In my laravel project I changed MyController name to OtherController, after doing that when I tried to run `php artisan route:list` this error occurs

```
[ReflectionException] Class App\Controller\MyController does not exist error
```

how to solve that and why this happens. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running `composer dump-autoload`